# Time clauses and present perfect progressive

Tags: future-time, present-perfect-progressive, time-reference

I have found a rule that we cannot use future forms when using time clauses including expressions such as: while, before, after, until/till, as, once, as soon as, as long as, **by the time**
Does this mean that below sentence is not grammatically correct if it contains "by the time"?

"How long will John have been working at the company **by the time** he retires?"

Comment: It's fine. Btw, it's not a clause but a preposition phrase introduced by the prep "by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct because after ***by the time***, the present tense is used, not the future. What the rule means is that it would be ***incorrect*** to say:

> How long will John have been working at the company by the time he ***will retire***?